# How to configure auto lock screen?

Tags: unity, mate

I'am using MATE Desktop Environment 1.5.7 in Ubuntu, I checked both options in Screensaver window but it's not working, so how to set auto lock screen as in Unity?

Answer (score 0):

In screensaver preferences, check "Lock screen when screensaver is active".

Answer (score 0):

Aside from checking that "Lock screen when screensaver is active" is selected, make sure that the mate screensaver package IS installed in the first place.

```
sudo apt-get install mate-screensaver
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
xdg-screensaver lock
```

works for me in mate